# Unable to calculate the aggregated mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in this form:

```
Customer_key  purcahse_amount   Date
12633           4435           08/07/2021
34243           7344           11/11/2021
54355           4642           10/11/2020
12633           6322           11/12/2021
```

Purchase_amount has few Nan values.... I want to replace the Nan values with mean of `purcahse_amount` but mean should be calculated for that particlar customer_key only. For example, If you see `customer_key=12633` is repeating in row 1 and row 4. So, for any row with `customer_key=12633`, if there is a missing value of `purcahse_amount`, then it be replaced with mean of that `purchase_amount` of all rows where `customer_key=12633`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` "Customer_key" and then compute the mean of "purchase_amount" and transform it for the DataFrame (we need to transform it to use it in `np.where` where the values to choose from must be broadcastable). Note that `mean` method skips NaN values by default, so it transforms the mean of non-NaN values.

Then using `np.where`, depending on if a "purchase_amount" is NaN or not fill in with group-specific mean or keep original.

```
means = df.groupby('Customer_key')['purchase_amount'].transform('mean')
df['purchase_amount'] = np.where(df['purchase_amount'].isna(), means, df['purchase_amount'])
```

or you can use `fillna`:

```
df['purchase_amount'] = df['purchase_amount'].fillna(means)
```

For example, if you had `df` as below:

```
   Customer_key  purchase_amount        Date
0         12633           4435.0  08/07/2021
1         34243           7344.0  11/11/2021
2         54355           4642.0  10/11/2020
3         12633           6322.0  11/12/2021
3         12633              NaN  11/12/2021
```

the both of the above options produce:

```
   Customer_key  purchase_amount        Date
0         12633           4435.0  08/07/2021
1         34243           7344.0  11/11/2021
2         54355           4642.0  10/11/2020
3         12633           6322.0  11/12/2021
3         12633           5378.5  11/12/2021
```

Comment: Your second step (ie. using fillna) is showing error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: Yes, it's working

Comment: Is it possible to somehow modify second one, so that it also works

Comment: Yes worked, Thanks